# Android Google AdMob

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I am using google admob and i already have banners on my app with the tokens from google add mob site. I tried them once without test device and it just loaded a random advertisment and not then one from the app of the token.

Is this wrong or my app will just load the correct ad when submitted on play store?

Thank you for the attention, 
Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean writing "and not then one from the app of the token" ? Use test device for testing. Publishing to Google Play have no impact on ads.

Comment: Sorry I meant "and not the one from the app of the token". Imagine on addmob I defined an add for the app "FlashScore" and then when I remove the test device and the banner loads, it appears an add that is nothing to do with the app "Flashscore".

Comment: Admob displays ads connected with user interests. In settings on website you can block categories that you don't want to display.

Comment: But if i choose an application to advertise shoudn't it just show the ad to installation of that app?